# Conjugating confluo for app title

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, conjugation

I have a software product called Continua.
I want to make another with a title like Confluo.

What are some reasonable variants of that word for this purpose — confluere, etc.?

I'm feeling like it should be 3 syllables and end in a consonant sound to distinguish it from the other app (like Confluence, though that feels a little boring and unmemorable to me), but I'd like to hear some possibilities.

The software is meant for bringing many people together to learn, communicate, add to, and explore each other's creative language projects.

(Hope I'm not breaking any forum rules by asking this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of related words and each has a number of possible forms:

- *confluere*, verb, "to flow together"

  - *confluo*, "I flow together"
  - *confluimus*, "we flow together"
  - *confluens*, "flowing together" (a participle)
  - *confluendo*, "by flowing together" (a gerund)
- *conflux* or *confluens* or *confluvium*, noun, "a place where rivers meet"
- *confluentia*, noun, "[the phenomenon of] flowing together" (essentially the Latin translation of "confluence")
- *confluus*, adjective, "flowing together"

  - *confluum*, singular neuter for a general thing flowing together
  - *conflua*, plural neuter for a number of things flowing together
  - *conflui*, masculine plural for a group of people flowing together
  - *confluis*, plural dative "for people who flow together"

This should give you a fair selection to get started with.
You can check more detailed meanings of these words in [a good online Latin dictionary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79) (which [do not include Google Translate](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79)) or ask in a comment here.
The list of possible forms is far from [exhaustive](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/921/79), so I am open to suggestions for relevant forms.

To me the most natural option of these seems to be *confluendo*, as it gives the impression of an active tool, something that I might want an app to be.

Comment: I agree; Confluendo's a mouthful, but it has just the right amount of strangeness and familiarity, and will immediately remind many people of 'crescendo', hopefully toward a concordant sound. Thank you greatly!

Comment: A number of these are going to get you in trouble with [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence).

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Good point! Unfortunately I can only advice on the language, and the legal responsibility of the name stays with the owner of the project anyway, so they need to check the name for availability.