# Miserere mei! Miserere nostri! Why genitive?

Tags: ecclesiastical-latin, dative, genitive

Why is the object of mercy ("me", "us") rendered in the genitive in these two cases?

- *miserere mei*  (Psalm li)
- *miserere nostri*  (Psalm cxxi)

I would expect accusative, or even dative.  But, genitive surprises me.

Actually, the dative appears in the *miserere nobis* of the Agnus Dei, so genitive does not seems to a hard rule here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, this is not specific to ecclesiastical Latin.
The same genitive is there in classical Latin as well.

The verb *miserere* is used impersonally.
It means roughly "to distress" or "to excite pity".
For example, *me miseret* means "I am distressed".
The reason of distress or the target of pity is indicated by genitive: *me miseret Marci* means "I pity Marcus".

The verb can also be used in passive voice.
This use is personal because passive gets rid of the impersonal subject.
Instead of *me miseret Marci* I can say *misereor Marci*.
The verbs *miserere* and *misereri* are listed separately in many dictionaries, but it makes most sense to me to see them as one verb used in both active and passive voice.

The word *miserere* is a passive imperative form of *miserere* — or the imperative of the deponent verb *misereri* if you wish to see it that way.
(This reminds me of [passive imperative forms of non-deponent verbs](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/62/79), which are rare but exist. It didn't occur to me before that *miserere* might count.)

The same construction is found with many impersonal verbs expressing feelings: *miserere*, *pigere*, *pudere*, *paenitere*, *taedere*.
Unfortunately I cannot fully explain why genitive is used in cases like this.
I see the object of pitying more as a cause than an actual object.
It helps me to think that the ablative *causa* is intended (whether or not this really is the case):
I might read *misereor Marci* as *misereor Marci causa*, "I pity because of Marcus".

I do not recall seeing *miserere* with dative in classical usage, but I may be mistaken.
Using dative is not surprising, though.
Dative is often used to indicate the entity that benefits or suffers from the action of a verb.
Therefore verbs like *auxiliari*, *favere*, *servire* and *deesse* require dative instead of accusative.
This idea of benefit is understandable with *miserere* as well.

Comment: (1) So, is miserere an intransitive verb?  (2) After reading your answer, the genitive feels to me like, "have mercy *concerning/about* me/us", while the dative feels like, "have mercy *for (the benefit of)* me/us".

Comment: @DavidCharles (1) *Miserere* (infinitive) is transitive, but the accusative object in *me miseret Marci* is *me*, not *Marci*. If you consider *misereri* deponent, it is intransitive. The word *miserere* (imperative) is a passive form. The active infinitive and the passive imperative look exactly alike. I hope this is not too confusing. (2) I never thought of it that way. I am not sure if such difference in meaning is intended when choosing dative instead of genitive, but it makes perfect sense.