# Is this a perfect passive infinitive with "esse" omitted?

Tags: lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, participle, passive-voice, perfect-tense, accusativus-cum-infinitivo

The following sentence comes from lines 8-9 of chapter XXIII of *Lingua latina per se illustrata. Familia Romana*:

> Tantum sciō epistulam Tūsculō missam et ā tabēllariō ad tē lātam esse.

I'm trying to understand what's the role of past participle *missam*. Should I interpret it as a perfect passive infinitive with "esse" omitted? That is, the meaning of the first half of the sentence would be

> Tantum sciō epistulam Tūsculō missam esse

and there would be an *accusativus cum infinitivo* construction in the passive voice.

Comment: It’s sharing the esse at the end with latam.

Comment: @Kingshorsey Should just go ahead and make that an answer.

Comment: @Kingshorsey: I agree with cmw. Could you please write an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you & Kingshorsey say, it is quite clear that in this example there are two perfect passive infinitives that are coordinated: *missam (esse)* and *latam esse*. Note that in this example it is not only natural but compulsory to interpret/analyze *missam* as *missam esse*, i.e. as a perfect passive infinitive.

However, it is worth pointing out that it is *not* always easy to determine whether *esse* is elliptical. Consider the following example, which also contains a perfect passive participle (*exstinctum*):

> cum auctorem senatus *exstinctum* laete atque insolenter tulit. (Cic. *Phil.* 9.7)
> ‘when he met the passing away of the senate’s adviser joyfully and insolently’

In this case it is more difficult to determine whether *esse* is elliptical or not. Syntactically speaking, this example is ambiguous:

(i) the construction *auctorem senatus exstinctum* can be an 'Accusativus cum Infinitivo' (AcI) structure with the verbal form *esse* elided (i.e. *auctorem senatus [exstinctum ESSE]*). Cf. the following example with *esse* being explicit:  *hoc ab isto praedone* ereptum esse *graviter tum et acerbe homines ferebant* (Cic. *Verr.* 2.1.152);

(ii) the construction *auctorem senatus exstinctum* can be a [dominant participle](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/409/is-victa-serpente-an-ablative-absolute/8793#8793) structure, whereby in this case there is no *esse* that has been elided (i.e. in this case the construction is *not* an AcI). The English translation above corresponds to this second reading, i.e. the one where *exstinctum* is a dominant participle.

---

Similarly, the topic of the elision of *esse* in compound infinitives can become crucial when discussing other subtle issues of Latin syntax. For example, at first sight, an example like the following one could be taken as a counterexample to the claim that [a "dative of agent" cannot be found in a non-verbal context](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12844/can-a-dative-of-agent-appear-in-an-ablative-absolute-construction-and-more-g). However, *ESSE* must be postulated here with the gerundive *paenitendum*. Otherwise, (my claim is that) the "dative of agent" *nobis* would not be licensed.

> Consilii nostri (...) nobis *paenitendum* putarem (Cic. Fam. 9.5.2). 'I should not have thought that we ought to repent of our policy’ (Evelyn S. Shuckburgh, 1908, Perseus site)

NB: incidentally this example is also interesting because it shows that, despite appearances, [the accusative case of the Experiencer with impersonal *paenitet/pudet...*-type verbs](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11191/what-is-the-grammatical-logic-of-impersonal-constructions-like-me-non-solum-p/21772#21772) (*nos consilii paenitet*) is not merely [lexical/idiosyncratic](https://people.umass.edu/ellenw/Woolford%20Lexical%20Case,%20Inherent%20Case,%20and%20Argument%20Structure.pdf). Otherwise, acc. *nos* would not be allowed to change to dat. *nobis* in the so-called "[periphrastic passive](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/21222/on-the-alleged-passive-meaning-of-so-called-miscalled-periphrastic-passive)" with gerundive.