# Can 'non' with gerundive mean both lack of obligation and negative obligation?

Tags: classical-latin, example-request, gerundive, negation

If a gerundive is used with *non*, can it mean both lack of obligation and negative obligation?
For example, can *non loquendum est* mean both "it is not necessary to speak" and "it is necessary not to speak"?
Does the word order have a role here?

If you want to argue that a gerundive with *non* can have a certain meaning, can you please **provide a classical quotation** where the meaning is clearly only one of the two possibilities?
In the cases I have seen, I find it hard to decide whether a lack of obligation or a negative obligation was meant.

To me the literal reading of such a phrase is lack of obligation, but negative obligation is possible too.
This was discussed in connection to [the earlier question concerning negative obligations](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/9526/79), but I wanted to ask this separate focused question to settle this matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following examples are of the negated gerundive clearly equivalent to a prohibition.

The pair *faciendum* / *non faciendum* is used to indicate positive and negative obligation, as evidenced by the parallelism with *sequi* / *fugere*.

> Videsne ut quibus summa est in voluptate perspicuum sit **quid iis faciendum** sit aut **non faciendum**? ut nemo dubitet eorum omnia officia quo spectare, **quid sequi**, **quid fugere debeant**? (Cic. De Fin. 4.17.46)

The grammarians consistently use *dicendum* and *non dicendum* to mean "an obligatory expression" and "a prohibited expression."

> Mi Paula et mi Aemilia **non dicendum**, quia mi masculini est generis
>   pronomen, non feminini, et ortum est a prima positione meus; **sed dicen-
>
>   dum** mea Paula et mea Aemilia, o meum caput, o meumque brachium. (Flavius Caper, De Orthographia, 102)

Legal Latin frequently uses the negated gerundive to signify prohibition. (The *Digests* itself is post-classical but consists largely of extracts of earlier Latin.)

> Proculus ait ... [in a case where one crime/tort could be prosecuted under two different legal statutes] si uno iudicio res esset iudicata, altero amplius **non agendum**. (Digesta, 9.2.27.11.3)

A slightly post-classical example clearly signifying prohibition:

> quod in facto reicitur, etiam in dicto non est recipiendum. (Tertullian, De Spectaculis, 17)

Answer (score 0):

How about "non loquendum est" = literally: "it ought not to be spoken"; equivalent to "it must not be spoken"; therefore your second choice: "it is necessary not to speak".

Suspect that if you want to introduce "necessary" you may have to deploy "necessitas"; not the gerundive-of-obligation impersonal-construction.