# Latin translation of "don't get caught"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, passive-voice, imperative, negation

I am looking for a translation of "don't get caught".
This phrase is the slogan of World Chase Tag (a tag competition), and it seems like they tried to put a Latin translation on their medals: [image](https://m.facebook.com/worldchasetag/photos/a.1532960823392861/3430530916969166/?type=3&source=54&ref=page_internal)

However, *Quit adepto raptus* looks very wrong to me, like a result of Google translate...

The phrase is a negation of the passive imperative mood. Passive imperative is apparently an odd thing in Latin ([see this post](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/62/are-there-examples-of-passive-imperative-forms-of-non-deponent-verbs-in-ancient)), and that's why I'm unsure what the best translation would be.

---

I think *capto* is the obvious choice for the verb, and the options I found online are the following:

- *noli / nolite* + passive infinitive: *noli captari / nolite captari*
- *ne* + passive infinitive: *ne captari*
- *ne* + passive imperative: *ne captare / ne captamini*
- *ne* + 2nd person subjunctive perfect passive: *ne captus/a sis / ne capti/ae sitis*

---

Are any of these options preferable, if correct at all?

Or is there maybe some other, non-literal translation?

I'd love to hear your feedback!

Comment: Do any of these answer your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd suggest a very slightly less literal translation using the verb *caveo* "beware", with *ne* and subjunctive:

> Cave ne capiaris!

Literally this means "watch out you don't get caught!". But this construction is often used as basically equivalent to a negative imperative, in contexts where you're warning someone against doing something. Some examples can be found [here](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=cave%20ne&first=1); another well-known one is *Cave ne eas* "Don't go!" in the story of [an omen to Crassus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omen_(ancient_Rome)). And it appears that one other sporting society has had the same idea: [*Cave ne cadas*](https://cavenecadas.nl/en/) "Watch out not to fall!" is the name of a Dutch horseriding association.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this sounds more "catchy" than the literal translation (pun intended) :)
I'm gonna send them an e-mail, let's see what they think!

Answer (score 3):

I think the best choice is *noli(te)* with infinitive.
It comes across as an order, not as a wish, and in this context I think an order "don't get caught" is a more suitable tone than a wish "I hope you won't get caught".
Positive passive imperatives are indeed rare and perhaps a little weird, but negative passive imperatives are easy to parse.
The same approach with *noli(te)* works equally well with active and passive.

Instead of *captare* (or *capto*) I would go with the more basic verb *capere* (or *capio*).
The former is derived from the latter.
Your suggestion *noli(te) captari* works well, and I would refine it to *noli(te) capi*.

The phrase *quit adepto raptus* indeed looks like [Google Translate nonsense](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79).
It could be translated as "the caught one is able for the one who has reached".
All of your suggestions make much more sense.