# Use of passive imperative of transitive verbs

Tags: passive-voice, imperative

I am so happy to have found this community.

I have 2 imperative sentences:

> Fenestram aperīre

and

> Fenestram aperī

I wonder if the passive form is correct and how could be translated into English or any other language.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for a nice question! I hope you'll stick around and ask more questions. Please take a look at our [tour] to see how to get the most out of your participation.

Comment: This question has now earned you enough reputation points to be able to vote. Please go around the site and vote up any questions and answers you find useful! That is the best way to show gratitude for the content people have volunteered to create.

Answer (score 6):

The active order *fenestram aperi* is perfectly valid.
The passive one *fenestram aperire* is ungrammatical and it is not clear what it should mean.
Therefore there is no point in trying to translate it; translation requires meaning.

The verb *aperire* is transitive and non-deponent.
[Passive imperative forms of such verbs are extremely rare](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/62/79) and are therefore best avoided when composing in Latin.

The form *aperire* as an imperative "be opened!" is valid despite being rare, but it is not used with an accusative.
To see this, let us first look at indicative sentences:

> 1. *Tu fenestram aperis.*
> 2. *Fenestra a te aperitur.*

These are essentially equivalent in meaning.
The subject of 1 is *tu* and that of 2 is *fenestra*.
When turning the descriptive indicative sentence into an order with an imperative, the order is given to the subject — and that subject should be *tu*.
**You would have to give your passive order to the window!**

If you are addressing a window instead of a person, these two indicative sentences work alike:

> 3. *Livia te aperit.*
> 4. *Tu a Livia aperiris.*

In 3 the subject is *Livia*, in 4 it is *tu* (the window).
The subject of an imperative clause should be *tu*, so an order would have to be based on 4:

> *[A Livia] aperire!*
> "Be opened [by Livia]!"

You can of course drop the agent, but I find that it clarifies what is going on.
There is no room for an accusative object, just like with (almost) any passive clause.

Comment: Thank you very much for the good explanation.

Comment: @babelpoint Welcome to the site. If your question has been satisfactorily answered/your problem has been solved, don't forget to click on the checkmark to mark it "solved." Let us know if you have any questions.